# Get div size with JS after CSS3 transformation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the height of an element in JavaScript after applying one/several CSS3 transformations on it.

```css
#transformed{
    transform:scale(.5);
}
```

Unfortunately, JQuery's outerHeight doesn't seem to do this naively.

```
$('#after').outerHeight(); //not affected by the transformation
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mQ2nT/

Comment: Inspector gives the same results.

Comment: Given @Musa's comment, you're probably out of luck - unless you want to start manually parsing CSS3 transform rules.

Comment: +1 Good question. So many votes on answer but not on the question which is a really interesting one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) to get the dimensions and positions after the transformation.

Simply, transform your elements, and:

```
$('#after')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
// note the [0], the function is DOM not jQuery's.
```

The best thing is that this will also return proper positions, dimensions after every transformation you apply.

You are free to `rotate`, `skew`, `translate` and everything else what CSS provides. gBCR will handle it.

Comment: Very nice! Didn't even think of it.

Comment: @Musa: Out of curiosity, is there a way to query `getBoundingClientRect` including the margins? When running your fiddle in Chrome and applying a margin to the divs, jquery can use `outerHight(true)`  to include margins but they seem to be ignored by the `getBoundingClientRect.height()` property. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/mQ2nT/4/

Comment: @FrançoisWahl, no. Margin isn't part of bounding box.

Comment: According to [this article](http://help.dottoro.com/ljvmcrrn.php), if using `getBoundingClientRect` `in IE7 or older, the returned object contains the coordinates in physical pixel size, while from version 8, it contains the coordinates in logical pixel size.` This seems to only matter though when zooming I gathered. +1 @psycketom  though as I think `getBoundingClientRect` is my personal preferred option too (now that I learned about it), unless I need to include margins or for some reason have to support zooming in IE7 or older.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl, CSS3 transforms and IE<9 doesn't make sense at all. As for the margins, that's an easy addition to gBCR.

Comment: @psycketom: Complete oversight on my behalf. Never dawned on me. You are correct off course. I'm going to remove my answer as it seems it is completely redundant to calculate your own size based on scale, seeing that `getBoundingClientRect` takes care of everything. As you said, if margins are to be taken into account it is easy to add. Even a simple `outerHeight(true) - outerHeight()` will do.