# Surrounding rectangle with and height of absolute rotated elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit-transform

I have a few DIVs (can be images too) elements with absolute position and rotated and scaled using CSS.

[image]

How can I calculate the total width and height that the element occupy (the rectangle around then). Checking the `offset()` of `position()` doesn't give me the right results.

I need a solution in Javascript/Jquery if possible, or the Math so I can calculate it myself if there isn't any other options. Thanks.

**What I've tried:**

- use offset, but it doesn't give me the right point
- position(), but it doesn't take the rotation into account

**CSS of an elements for example:**

```
position:absolute;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-280deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: 43px 33px;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getBoundingClientRect()` will be able to give you the position and dimensions of each of your elements, after any CSS `transform`s are applied to them.

From there, it's a matter of figuring out the total height (subtracting the minimum `top` from the maximum `bottom`) and width (subtracting the minimum `left` from maximum `right).

[Here's a fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/_ajm/Q7t96/1/) and [here's a semi-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664792/get-div-size-with-js-after-css3-transformation) that should get you started.