# How can I get an element's position (relative to its container) before `transform: scale()`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a grid of floated, fixed-sized boxes in a container. I need to get the position of each box relative to the container using JS/jQuery. I know I can set `position: relative` on the container and use jQuery `$box.position()`, but it doesn't work because my `<body>` is scaled using `transform: scale()`. (I have another script that scales the `<body>` to match the viewport width, similar to [this](https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/#article-header-id-1), but for this question, just know that the `<body>` will have `transform: scale()` with some arbitrary scaling factor.)

jQuery's `$box.position()` seems to return the position **after** scaling, but I want the original position **before** scaling. For example, if each box has `width: 300px; margin-right: 10px`, then a box in the third column should have left offset `620px` (before scaling). However, `$box.position().left` gives `310px` (after scaling) if the `<body>` has `transform: scale(0.5)`.

Is there a way to get the position **before** scaling, without knowing the scaling factor? I found the native DOM method `getBoundingClientRect()`, but (1) [it still gives the position after scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664792/get-div-size-with-js-after-css3-transformation) and (2) [it's relative to the viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) rather than the container.

Thanks.

Comment: i'm confused. You asked a question and answered it at the same time? Are you essentially posting it out here so that it may help others in the future?

Comment: @Observer, yes actually, that's the idea. StackOverflow encourages users to answer their own questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer . When you ask a question, there's an "Answer your own question" checkbox at the bottom, which allows you to submit a question and answer at the same time. This is actually my first time doing so. Just wanted to contribute back to StackOverflow after learning so much from this website. =)

Comment: Cool, Thanks for answering my comment-question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the native DOM properties [`offsetLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft) and [`offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) instead. [Browser support](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#elementview) looks good: basically all browsers and IE8+. I tried these properties and they seem to give the correct position before scaling in Chrome, Firefox, and IE11 at least.

Because they're native DOM properties, you need `$element[0]` to get the underlying DOM element first: `$box[0].offsetLeft` and `$box[0].offsetTop`. Also, note that they give the position of the top-left corner of the element's border box, *not* margin box.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Seemed simple enough, just give me the position before the `transform: scale` happens, but all the answers I was finding were pages of JS code!! Luckily I found yours. Thanks man!